# How to use refresh tokens in device flow

Tags: github, oauth-2.0, jwt, refresh-token

I am currently using the [GitHub device flow](https://docs.github.com/en/apps/oauth-apps/building-oauth-apps/authorizing-oauth-apps#device-flow) to authenticate my CLI. All fine and good.

Now, I want to use the refresh token so that users don't need to go through the device flow every 8 hours. However, the [docs](https://docs.github.com/en/apps/creating-github-apps/authenticating-with-a-github-app/refreshing-user-access-tokens#refreshing-a-user-access-token-with-a-refresh-token) say the `client_secret` is required to exchange tokens, and I of course can't expose this through my CLI. How would one refresh a token from a CLI in this case?